# Edit values from a variable based on multiple values from multiple variable within a dataframe

Tags: r

I am new to R so please bear with me.

I have a dataframe of 8891 obs. of 4 variables:

```
Survived: int  0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 ...
Sex       : Factor w/ 2 levels "female","male": 2 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 1 1 ...
Age      : num  22 38 15 78 35 NA 54 2 27 14 ...
Fare : num  120 120 120 120 ...

Sex <- c("female","male", "male", "male")
Survive <- c(0,1,1,0)
Age <- c(22,38,15,78)
Fare <- c(120,120,120,120)
dataframe <- data.frame(Sex, Survive, Age, Fare)
#View(dataframe)
```

I am trying to create another variable `FixedFare` where the values from the variable `Fare` will be divided by 2 based on values from variable `Survived` and variable `Age`.

Basically, if the value in `Survived` is 1 and the value in `Age` is <= 16  and >= 60 then divide the value X in `Fare` by 2. And if it comes across `NA` then just mark `NA`. All this is within the same data frame.

I am not sure how to do this. I’ve searched all related questions in Stackoverflow for a solution but couldn’t find one similar to my question.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ifelse` approach assigns values based on the conditions provided:

```
df$Fare <- ifelse(df$Survived == 1 & (df$Age <= 16 | df$Age >= 60), df$Fare/2, df$Fare)
```

Using the example in the question we wrap the function call in `transform`:

```
transform(dataframe, Fare = ifelse(Survive == 1 & (Age <= 16 | Age >= 60), Fare/2, Fare))
#     Sex Survive Age Fare
#1 female       0  22  120
#2   male       1  38  120
#3   male       1  15   60
#4   male       0  78  120
```

Comment: This is awesome Pierre! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

We create a logical vector 'i1' based on the condition that 'Survive' is 1 and Age is either less than 17 or greater than 59.  Use that index to subset 'Fare', divide by 2, and assign the output to a new column 'FixedFare'.

```
 i1 <- with(df1, Survive==1 & (Age < 17 | Age > 59))
 df1$FixedFare[i1] <- df1$Fare[i1]/2
```

It is not clear whether we need `NA` for the elements that doesn't meet the condition or not.  If we need the original 'Fare' values instead of NA.

```
 df1$FixedFare[!i1] <- df1$Fare[!i1]
```

---

Or we can do this using `data.table` which would be faster

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[,FixedFare:= Fare][Survive==1 & (Age < 17 | Age > 59), FixedFare:= Fare/2]
```

Comment: Hi akrun, I tried the code and got this message Warning message:
In Ops.factor(dataframe$FixedFare[i1], 2) : ‘/’ not meaningful for factors

Comment: @User1175 It means your 'Fare' column is not numeric.  Try converting to numeric. i.e. `df1$Fare <- as.numeric(as.character(df1$Fare))` before doing the operation.

Comment: @User1175 Are you sure you got the warnings.  I was able to get the expected output based on the example you provided.